# Github actions get trigger in branch when it shouldnt

Tags: github-actions

So I have the main branch and I want to be able to deploy to production when ever I have a push or a pull_request and I want to deploy develop environment tag any branch with 'develop', except main.
The following is on my main.yml

```
name: Create and Upload Prod Container and Deploy to Prod Amazon ECS

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
```

I am currently in the develop branch as you can see

[image]

But when ever I push a commit to the develop branch I am seeing the main.yml is being called. I can tell the main.yml is being called because it is the title "Create and Upload Prod Container and Deploy to Prod Amazon ECS"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing a Pull Request triggering your workflow and it's correct based on what you have in the YML file.

There must be a PR existing that has a base being `main` and when you push to `develop` it got synchronized - as you can see in your own attached screenshot.
This is the second part of your YML `pull_request`: every Pull Request with a base to `main` will also trigger your workflow.

If you want to just have `push` to `main` remove the second part.
Merges of PRs will be working then as those are treated as a `push`, so your first condition will be met.

Answer (score -1):

You provided not valid yml content. Try to correct the indentation. You can check the validity for example here https://onlineyamltools.com/convert-yaml-to-json

```
name: Create and Upload Prod Container and Deploy to Prod Amazon ECS

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
```

Comment: yea sorry the code tag damaged the yml format